# Merging cells with Office 365 excel documents VB.NET (or C#) when running multiple threads

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, multithreading, merge

Merging cells using Office interops works perfectly on all versions of Office including Office 2010 and Office 365. However, when multiple threads are running to create multiple Excel documents at the same time (speeds up the process when you have a multi threaded application), the `.Merge()` function on a range throws an error when running Office 365. Thoughts?

`rng.Merge()` throws an error when using a multi threaded application.

The following error comes up:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Office applications are STA. Probably worth reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019

Comment: *Don't* try to use multiple threads. You can speed up the process a *lot* though if you modify the code to reduce cross-process calls. This isn't just interop, your application is making a cross-process call to Office. Every property access, every call costs *hundreds* if not thousands of times more than accessing a local object. Fixing the code will improve performance far more than multithreading

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - "Every property access, every call costs hundreds if not thousands of times more than accessing a local object. " - Is the recommendation to use a third party library to create office apps? Can you elaborate with an example as to how to improve performance without using multiple threads?

Comment: You haven't posted any code so no. I don't know if you're trying to create an Excel sheet, in which case you *don't* need Excel at all, or automate some task, in which case the code should be optimized. The cross-thread cost isn't something new or specific to Office apps. There *are* ways to fill a range of cells in a single operation instead of modifying them one by one.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos - The application creates a mix of automated excel and power-point documents. It uses interop to create these documents. What would your suggestion be? Not use interop at all? The application creates some automated charts using the in-built charting control and plonks them on power-point documents. The excel documents are heavily formatted as well. Also, in terms of filling a range of cells, the application does create ranges and applies the changes to the range instead of modifying them one by one.